# Error with IbisTypeError using row validation from professional-services-data-validator tool

Tags: python, sql-server, validation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ibis

So I'm using an open-source tool to compare the row-by-row data between 2 tables sitting in 2 different databases in in MSSQL and the other in Snowflake.

The connection setups for both were fine. I could run the row count comparison successfully and got the count using the cmd below:

```
data-validation validate column -sc snowflake -tc snowflake -tbls MY_SCH.MY_TABLE
```

However I ran into issues when running the row-by-row comparison. For a test, I am comparing a snowflake table to itself. The cmd is as below:

```
data-validation validate row -sc snowflake -tc snowflake -tbls MY_SCH.MY_TABLE --primary-keys MY_PRIMARY_KEY --hash '*'
```

Where:

- `row`: type of data validation,
- `-sc`: source connection
- `-tc`: target connection
- `tbls`: table name(s)
- `--primary-keys`: the primary key column being used to match between the 2 tables
- `--hash`: `*` for validating all fields or a list of field names for a selected list only

This error message followed , I've tried comparing different tables, selected columns, using SQL Server database. All came out with the same error:

```
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ibis\common\validators.py", line 467, in sequence_of
    raise IbisTypeError(f'Arg must have at least {min_length} number of elements')
ibis.common.exceptions.IbisTypeError: Arg must have at least 1 number of elements
```

The Github repo for the data validation tool is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services-data-validator

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: why not load both tables into a dataframe ,and  use  that to compare

Comment: Comparing dataframes involves knowing the exact mappings of the table columns between the databases and independent connection handling for different types of database and some sort of reporting formatting and implementation. If I have hundreds of table, dataframe comparison might not be feasible. This tool scales and handles many of those angles out of the box.

Comment: Did you read the docs or are you making up the arguments as you go? It says: `--tables-list or -tbls SOURCE_SCHEMA.SOURCE_TABLE=TARGET_SCHEMA.TARGET_TABLE` and it doesn't seem like you have specified the `=TARGET_SCHEMA.TARGET_TABLE` part in your example

Comment: Yes, I was making it up as I go, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as below:

> data-validation validate row -sc snowflake -tc snowflake -tbls
> MY_SCH.MY_TABLE=MY_SCH.MY_TABLE --primary-keys MY_PRIMARY_KEY --hash *

The key is to follow the syntax of for parameter -tbls `MY_SCH.MY_TABLE=MY_SCH.MY_TABLE` and remove all quotations.